# LaTeX does not render the picture?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, ieeetran

I am a bit new LaTeX, so having some difficulties.

I am writing a paper using the IEEtran template. I use the graphicx package to insert the figures: `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`

I try to add the figure using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{testy.pdf}
\caption{Simulation Results.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
```

The figure is in the same directory with the *.tex file

But, after the tex file is complied, the borders of the figure show up in the resulting pdf, also the captions are there, but the picture itself in not rendered. There is a strange border with the name of the picture within it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using latex or pdflatex? also make sure you don't have the `[draft]` package option specified (which is the most likely cause of just printing the filename)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are perfectly right david, I had completely forgotten that I was compiling in draft mode... after drinking some pepsi, after sugar went to my brain I remembered the "issue", but you have already come up with the suggestion! kudos :)

Comment: well I implemented that so even after these years it's not so hard to remember which options cause teh filename to be printed:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hohohohohoho, c'mon, is that you really?... 
earlier today I was trying to download the package, and certainly read your name in the documentation; Later, when I read the response to my question, I had the feeling that I know the name, but couldn't recall...

#respect for all the work! #takeabow sir!

Comment: \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{neferiti.pdf}
\caption{Simulation Results.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
\end{document} Use this. It worked for me. Please replace the figure.